# Insert into Substring doesn't insert at index

Tags: c#, while-loop, insert, stringbuilder

I have the following code, that is intended to loop through and add values to a string value. 
Every other value, starting at index 0 of string builder, `RepeatIndexes`, is supposed to always be a squiggly. and the other value from a specific index in a library I have elsewhere. Just pretend that

```
char InsertThis = indexJustForRepetas[IndexOfIndexes[RepeatTime]];
```

^-- ='s   ' X '   --^

here's the actual code/loop:

```
StringBuilder RepeatIndexes = new StringBuilder("");
int ZeroPosition = 0;        //for the indexes which will remain blank until the next loop-
int charPosition = 1;
int RepeatTime = 0;       //1 thru final --^-                         1^
while (NumberHalf > 0)   //find and replace the char that was repeated within the string, 'AccountableToRepeats', with something that we can decipher later, during decryption- 
{

    RepeatIndexes.Insert(ZeroPosition, "~"); //inserting a squiggly line until next loop-
    char InsertThis = indexJustForRepetas[IndexOfIndexes[RepeatTime]];   //find char at IndexOfIndexes to add into position-
    RepeatIndexes.Insert (charPosition, InsertThis);
    RepeatTime =RepeatTime +2;
    ZeroPosition = ZeroPosition + 2; 
    NumberHalf = NumberHalf - 1;
}
```

the index for the squiggly lines ('~'), starts at 0: `int ZeroPosition = 0;`

The index for the characters ( "X" ), starts at 1: `int charPosition = 1;`

But for some reason the output I'm getting is: `~XXX~~`

when it should be: `~X~X~X`

is there something about the nature of string builder or `insert()` I'm not understanding?
The loop looks like it should be increment correctly to be but the output just doesn't make any sense to me.

I hope this questions within the bounds of appropriateness for this service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I think the problem is that `charPosition` is not being updated. You need to update `charPosition` with the same values as `RepeatTime` and `ZeroPosition`. So, add `charPosition += 2;` in the while loop. What's happening is that `'X'` is always being inserted at position 1 (the position after the first `~`).

Also, you're over complicating it by using `Insert` and all those indexes. `RepeatTime` and `ZeroPosition` have the same value so you don't need both.

You can use `StringBuilder`'s `.Append()` to add text to the end of a string. I've used string interpolation `${var}` and assumed `numberHalf = 3` but this should do what you want:

```
    StringBuilder repeatIndexes = new StringBuilder();
    int numberHalf = 3;
    // int repeatTime = 0;
    while (numberHalf > 0)
    {
        // replace below line with your char in array
        char insertThis = 'X'; //indexJustForRepetas[IndexOfIndexes[repeatTime]];   
        repeatIndexes.Append($"~{insertThis}");
        // repeatTime += 1 // needed for array call above. +1 or +2 depending on your intention
        numberHalf = numberHalf - 1;
    }
    var outString = repeatIndexes.ToString();


    output:
    ~X~X~X
```

You could split the line `repeatIndexes.Append($"~{insertThis}")` into 2 if you prefer:

```
repeatIndexes.Append("~");
repeatIndexes.Append(insertThis);
```